# How to create a truly blank project in Visual Studio (2017)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

It seems like there should be a way to do this, but I just can't seem to do it. I love VS and I want to use it to develop web apps that are strictly HTML/Javascript based. In other words, no C#, no VB, no resulting /bin folder, no web config, no nothing. A blank project meaning "truly 100% blank" and not trying force me into some Microsoft technology or otherwise. I just want to use VS to write the code because it's still the best HTML/Javascript/Typescript/Everything-else-script editor out there.

Any thoughts on this? Can it even be done? Or is VS just too dependent on "Microsoft thinking" to allow this?

Answer (score 8):

What you have described is indeed possible in Visual Studio 2017 Community.

[image]

**Step 1)** Create a new Project via *File* / *New* / *Project*

[image]

**Step 2)** Select *Other Project Types* / *Visual Studio Solutions* / *Blank Solution*.

[image]

**Step 3)** Right-click the newly created solution and select *Add* / *New Solution Folder*. This step may not seem important, but it seems that **files cannot be added directly to a solution without first creating a "Solution Folder"**. This solution folder is virtual in that it **does not correspond a physical folder location**.

[image]

**Step 4)** Now right-click the newly created Solution Folder and select *Add* / *Existing Item*.

[image]

**Step 5)** Insert all the files you want to add. These may be added via the menu option in Step 4 or otherwise drag-and-dropped onto the solution folder (*not* the solution itself!).

[image]

Notice that even after creating the new solution and adding files, the only things created by Visual Studio 2017 are the usual *.vs* internal folder and the solution file itself.

Comment: You don't show what to do for the name and location. When I did this it did not create a folder (using the name I provided) as is normal for solutions. However if I selected (checked) the checkbox in the New Project window to create a folder for the solution then it used the name as expected and then Step 3 is not necessary. I also checked the checkbox to create a new Git repository and it was set up properly too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard or found a template online that will do this. I'm assuming you meant just HTML, JS/TypeScript, CSS/SASS etc. without .NET for "truly blank". Me I just delete the files I don't use :)

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. However I find that, for example, if I start with an C#/asp.net project, and delete everything, VS still thinks it's an asp.net project, so it creates a /bin folder and forces me to have a web.config file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want is to start with an empty canvas like Blank Solution and then add your files in the solution. You don't actually need to have library/console/web projects in a solution, you could just have html and js and whatever you use for web development.
You can find the Blank Solution when you create a new project under the Other Project Types tab.